# Persisting Svelte stores to localStorage

Tags: local-storage, svelte, svelte-store

I have an app that uses Svelte (SSR with Astro), and I'm trying to persist my data to `localStorage`.

There just isn't enough documentation about this IMO, since I seem to be running into brick walls constantly.

So far I have this store defined:

```
import { writable } from 'svelte/store'

function createCart() {
    const { subscribe, set, update } = writable([]);
    return {
        subscribe,
        update: (item) => update(value => [...value, item]),
        remove: (item) => update(n => {
                    if(n.length > 0) n.pop() // only remove last item
                    return n // update the store value
                }),
        empty: () => set([])
    };
}

export const cart = createCart()
```

To save to `localStorage` (and not mess up my SSR) I've implemented this:

```
import { writable } from 'svelte/store'

function createCart() {

    const defaultCartValue = []
    const isClient = typeof window !== 'undefined'
    const initialValue = isClient ? window.localStorage.getItem('cart') : defaultCartValue;

    const { subscribe, set, update } = writable(
        isClient 
            ? window.localStorage.setItem('cart', initialValue) 
            : defaultCartValue
    );
    return {
        subscribe: subscribe(value => localStorage.setItem('cart', ([
            value,
            ...initialValue
        ]))),
        update: (value) => isClient 
                ? window.localStorage.setItem(
                        'cart', 
                        JSON.stringify([...value, item])
                  )
                : update(value => [...value, item]),
        // TODO: fix remove items from localStorage
        remove: (item => update(n => {
                    if(n.length > 0) n.pop()
                    return n
                })
        ),
        empty: () => isClient
            ? window.localStorage.setItem('cart', defaultCartValue)
            : set(defaultCartValue)
    };
}

export const cart = createCart()
```

I keep getting `Cannot read property 'unsubscribe' of undefined` followed by `stop is not a function`.

Can anyone help me understand why I might be seeing those 2 errors?

Answer (score 3):

The error you're getting:

> Cannot read property 'unsubscribe' of undefined followed by stop is not a function.

That's because the `subscribe` method of a store *has to* return an `unsubscribe` (aka `stop`) function. This is not stressed very much in the docs, but it shows in the signature of the method:

```js
subscribe: (subscription: (value: any) => void) => (() => void)
```

But your own code doesn't do that and, for what it's worth, it probably doesn't really do what you intended:

```js
        subscribe: subscribe(value => localStorage.setItem('cart', ([
            value,
            ...initialValue
        ]))),
```

You're calling the original `subscribe` *immediately* when creating the store, as opposed to when a new subscriber is registered. Since the original `subscribe` does return an `unsubscribe` function, you don't get a "is not a function" error when trying to subscribe. But you don't get a subscription either, and the `unsubscribe` function does not return another function, which explains the error you're seeing.

What you want instead is something like that:

```js
subscribe: subscriber => {
  // do something on every new subscriber

  // subscribing 
  const unsubscribe = originalSubscribe(value => {
    // do something every time the value change FOR EVERY SUBSCRIBER

    subscriber(value) // notify the subscriber of the new value
  }

  // custom unsubscribe function
  return () => {
    // do something each time a subscriber unsubscribes

    unsubcribe() // unsubscribe from the original store
  }
}
```

If you follow the comments in the previous snippet, you should realize that wrapping `subscribe` is probably not what you want to persist to `localStorage`, because the "hooks" you get this way are *for every subscriber*, not once per store.

---

One way to achieve what you want would be to override the `set` and `update` method of a writable store like `svelte-local-storage-store` [does](https://github.com/joshnuss/svelte-local-storage-store/blob/86462b8be213e6a3681de2bb1d8280aab5065f31/index.ts#L41):

```js
    const {subscribe, set} = store

    stores[key] = {
      set(value: T) {
        updateStorage(key, value)
        set(value)
      },
      update(updater: Updater<T>) {
        const value = updater(get(store))

        updateStorage(key, value)
        set(value)
      },
      subscribe
    }
```

---

Another dead simple and conveniently modular way of doing it is simply to subscribe to your store.

```js
// a guard because we only want this in the clients
if (!isSSR() && typeof localStorage !== 'undefined') {
  originalStore.subscribe(value => {
    localStorage.setItem('key', JSON.stringify(value))
  })
}
```

This only applies if you don't mind having your store "always active" though; that is, you'd probably don't want to do that with a "rich" store that would do a request when it gets its first subscriber, for example.

---

Yet another way to leverage the original store's `subscribe` all while avoiding the pitfall of eagerly subscribing to it, would be to wrap the above logic in a readable store.

```js
const createPersistedStore = initialValue => {
    const internal = writable(initialValue)

    const persisting = readable(initialValue, set => {
        // called when the store becomes active (i.e. first subscriber arrives)

        const unsubscribe = internal.subscribe(value => {

            updateLocalStorage(value) // <== will see each change once

            set(value)
        })

        return () => {
            // called when the store becomes inactive (i.e. last subscriber leaves)
            unsubscribe()
        }
    })

    return {
        set: internal.set,
        update: internal.update,
        subscribe: persisting.subscribe,
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

This isn't going to help me understand svelte stores better, but this NPM module was a quick solution:

https://www.npmjs.com/package/svelte-local-storage-store